# multi-language in metadata itunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, metadata

I want to publish my application into app store, while proceeding I've faced a problem with the language, in fact my application contains arabic data, so I want to put the description in arabic and the keywords are in both languages (arabic and english) because my application name is in english, there is no arabic language in the drop down list:
[image]

and here they tell me to put my information in english, which is logic because I've choose the english like default language:
[image]

what I want is to enable put information in arabic also,

please help because I am proceeding it but this problem stops my procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for Arabic on the App Store. (You can see all available iTunes languages at http://smoothlocalize.com in the "Choose Language" section)

While you can set your In-app text to Arabic, you cannot set your iTunes text for Arabic. I assume they will support this in the future, but as of today it is not possible.

Comment: ok, I put the description and keywords in the metadata uploads, in both languages arabic and english, and I localized the application also in both languages, may Apple support this in the future.